# How to configure a Nexus3 repository for Gauge plugins?

Tags: nexus3, getgauge

I'm in the process of introducing Gauge in one of my projects. One pre-requisite is providing all development environments with a Nexus3 local repository of external dependencies.

Raw repositories should be the way to go, but it's not clear to me how to configure Nexus and the development environments in order to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

Gauge allows you to configure your repository by setting [`gauge_repository_url`](https://docs.gauge.org/latest/configuration.html).

However it expects a particular format of metadata. You might want to see [gaueg-nightly-repository](https://github.com/getgauge/gauge-nightly-repository) for a reference.

This nightly repository can be used by setting `gauge_repository_url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/getgauge/gauge-nightly-repository/master/`.